# Can not compile software dependent on java3d, with relevant jars on classpath

Tags: java, ant, classpath, java-3d

I am building a piece of software that depends on the java3d package. When compiling, I get the following error messages.

```
[javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
ViewManager.java:162: error: package javax.media.j3d does not exist
```

And many other errors indicating that none of the java3d packages exist or are at least accessible. However, if I `echo $CLASSPATH`, I get the following output.

```
.:/myhome/j3d/lib/ext/j3dcore.jar:/myhome/j3d/lib/ext/j3dutils.jar:/myhome/j3d/lib/ext/vecmath.jar
```

which indicates, at least to me, that java3d is installed correctly and accessible. I am building this project from ant. Is there something I am missing in order to compile dependent jars from within ant?

Comment: You're checking $CLASSPATH, but perhaps (as is exceedingly common) the `build.xml` specifies an alternate CLASSPATH to use via the -cp command-line switch?

Comment: Well that makes sense. So the solution is to change the build.xml to reference the jars I want? For example if in the build it says `classpath = ${classpath}`, I just need to edit that attribute to include the right jars correct?

Comment: Read the `build.xml` to see where it wants to get the location of Java3D from; there may be a property you should set or something along those lines.

Comment: There really isn't. It is a big file, but all but one of the classpath's set in the build file all have classpath=${classpath}. It also happens that all of these that redefine the classpath all depend on that target. I went ahead and edited this classpath to have the jars and the build was successful. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you have it on your shell's classpath, does not mean it is included in the classpath that is used to build by ant. There is a `<property>` that can be set inside of a `target` specified by ant.

Make sure all the jars you need are inside that classpath.